# How can i increase the performance of query in PostgreSQL 9.5?

Tags: sql, query-optimization, database-performance, postgresql-9.5

The below mentioned query calls another procedure **getcurrencyexchangerate()**. How can this be called once and used everywhere? How can below condition **"CASE WHEN in_currency != -1 THEN speedy.currency_code = in_currency ELSE TRUE END"** be used outside the where clause so that performance can be improved ?

```
SELECT 
    -- LOGINS
    COALESCE(sum( 
        CASE WHEN speedy.base_transaction_type IN ('logins') THEN
        speedy.count ELSE 0 END),0) as login,
    -- REGISTRATIONS
    COALESCE(sum( 
        CASE WHEN speedy.base_transaction_type IN ('registrations') THEN
        speedy.count ELSE 0 END),0) as registration,
    -- COMPLETED DEPOSITS
    COALESCE(sum( 
        CASE WHEN speedy.base_transaction_type IN ('manual_deposit', 'deposit') AND
        LOWER(speedy.status) IN ('success', 'pending approval') THEN
        (speedy.amount_1 * (CASE WHEN in_currency = -1 THEN (SELECT getcurrencyexchangerate(speedy.currency_code)) ELSE 1 END) )
        ELSE 0 END),0) as deposit,
    -- COMPLETED WITHDRAWS
    COALESCE(sum( 
        CASE WHEN speedy.base_transaction_type IN ('withdraw') AND
        LOWER(speedy.status) IN ('success') THEN
        (speedy.amount_2 * (CASE WHEN in_currency = -1 THEN (SELECT getcurrencyexchangerate(speedy.currency_code)) ELSE 1 END) )
        ELSE 0 END),0) as withdraw,
    -- BONUS SUM
    COALESCE(sum( 
        CASE WHEN speedy.base_transaction_type IN ('bonus', 'manual_bonus') AND
        LOWER(speedy.status) IN ('success') THEN
        (speedy.amount_1 * (CASE WHEN in_currency = -1 THEN (SELECT getcurrencyexchangerate(speedy.currency_code)) ELSE 1 END) )
        ELSE 0 END),0) as bonus,
    -- MANUAL BONUS SUM
    COALESCE(sum( 
        CASE WHEN speedy.base_transaction_type IN ('manual_bonus') AND
        LOWER(speedy.status) IN ('success') THEN
        (speedy.amount_1 * (CASE WHEN in_currency = -1 THEN (SELECT getcurrencyexchangerate(speedy.currency_code)) ELSE 1 END) )
        ELSE 0 END),0) as manualbonus,
    -- BONUS WAGERED
    COALESCE(sum( 
        CASE WHEN speedy.base_transaction_type IN ('bonus_wagered') AND
        LOWER(speedy.status) IN ('success') THEN
        (speedy.amount_1 * (CASE WHEN in_currency = -1 THEN (SELECT getcurrencyexchangerate(speedy.currency_code)) ELSE 1 END) )
        ELSE 0 END),0) as bonuswager
FROM speedy_reports_data AS speedy
WHERE 
    speedy.for_date BETWEEN '2017-08-31' AND '2018-08-31' AND
    (CASE WHEN in_currency != -1 THEN speedy.currency_code = in_currency ELSE TRUE END)
```

The speedy_reports_data table has composite key on columns (for_date, skin_id, country_code, currency_code, is_test, base_transaction_type, status) in the same order. No other index is there on this table

Comment: which value are  possible for in_currency ?? your case in where seems not correct

Comment: Integer numbers will come in currency where each id is mapped to a currency. For instance 1-> USD  2->EURO. For -1 value , data of all the currency needs to be taken together and converted to a single currency

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your query

for  speedy_reports_data  table  a composite

```
index  on columns (for_date, in_currency, currency_code )
```

Comment: This is not a covering index (I don't think is necessary anyway). It will allow access by the index. However, I'm not sure how fast the index access will be since he's selecting a major part of the table (a whole year). Good starting point nevertheless. Upvoting.

Comment: @TheImpaler  . i have suggested  al least and index  with columns involved  in where  . don't cover  all the column requested   ,,but shoild help  for the where clause  evaluation  .